# Chrome autofill does not work with ng-model-options in Angular

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, autofill

I'm using the [autofill-event polyfill](https://github.com/tbosch/autofill-event) for a form in Angular. For some of the fields, I've used `ng-model-options` within the input field. For those fields in Chrome, the model doesn't update, and fields fail validation when they should succeed. If I don't use `ng-model-options` everything works fine. Any thoughts on how to fix this in a way that allows me to still use `ng-model-options`?

Here's the code for the validation that gives a false negative:

```
<label class="control-label" for="city">City</label>
<input type="text" id="city" name="city" ng-model="contactForm.contact.city" 
placeholder="City" class="form-control" ng-minlength="2" 
ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" required>
  <span ng-show="paymentForm.city.$error.required && !paymentForm.city.$untouched 
|| paymentForm.city.$error.required
|| paymentForm.address.$error.minlength && !paymentForm.address.$untouched
|| paymentForm.address.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Enter your city</span>
```

Comment: you need to write your attribute like ng-maxlength="2" ng-minlength="2" instead of ng-minlength=2

Comment: @Shohel Thanks for bringing that to my attention. Fixed it above.

Comment: will I write my answer?